# How to pass typescript dynamic type as a parameter to react custom hooks?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Is there any way to pass types as a parameter or something to another component? something like this, passing a dynamic type so I can type automatically third parties hooks outside my custom hook

```
const hook = useCustomHook<DynamicType>()
```

and in the custom hook do something like

```
 export const useCustomHook = () => {
     return useAnotherLibraryHook<DynamicType>()
 }
```

Comment: So a [generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-types)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called [generic type parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html). Simply put:

```
export const useCustomHook = <T extends any>() => {
  return useAnotherLibraryHook<T>()
}
```

However you will want to exchange `any` with something narrower that is relevant to the library, perhaps one of its internal types.